# Given CR's question title policy, how to title a second question about the same program?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, titles

[Originally asked in 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49203226#49203226)

If we're asking a second CR question involving the same software, is it acceptable to give it nearly the same title? What is best practice for naming these questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating different titles for follow-ups is difficult, so most follow-up questions tend to have very similar titles which is perfectly fine. Some options for naming a follow-up question is:

- XYZ Program v2
- Follow-up to XYZ Program
- XYZ Program continued
- XYZ Program - follow-up

If you want to be creative, you can try to be creative with your titles for the follow-ups. My favorite is this sequence of questions:

1. [A grid and a menu walked into a program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78014/a-grid-and-a-menu-walked-into-a-program)
2. [The grid looked at the menu and said "Something with class, please"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78208/the-grid-looked-at-the-menu-and-said-something-with-class-please)

Comment: I think `v2` kind of titles are better because `v3` is better than `followup of followup`